# Node-red email node keeps crashing

Tags: email, node-red

I have a simple email node and debug-node set-up within a web application using node red. 
The email node has refresh time set to 5 seconds. and protocol IMAP. 
I have a gmail account logged in.

Node-red crashes with the following error:
(Happens rather quickly when I receive an email with an attachment of > 10mb).

The TypeError is on different properties like 'name', 'type' '11456' etc...

```
10 Jul 17:00:28 - [info] Starting flows
10 Jul 17:00:28 - [info] Started flows
10 Jul 17:00:37 - [red] Uncaught Exception:
10 Jul 17:00:37 - TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:431:22)
    at Connection._resTagged (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:1535:22)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:194:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Parser._resTagged (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:175:10)
    at Parser._parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:139:16)
    at Parser._tryread (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:82:15)
    at TLSSocket.Parser._cbReadable (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:53:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
```

Versions:

```
10 Jul 17:00:27 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.18.7
10 Jul 17:00:27 - [info] Node.js  version: v8.11.3
10 Jul 17:00:27 - [info] Linux 4.15.0-24-generic x64 LE
```

Package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "imap": "^0.8.19",
    "mailparser": "^0.6.2",
    "nodemailer": "^1.11.0",
```

Comment: Since you've also asked about this on Discourse and raised and issue do you want to close this question.

Comment: When I have a solution I intend to link them and close this.

Comment: maybe in that case you can also add the reference to the Discourse discussion and the issue you have raised.

Comment: https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/issues/461


https://discourse.nodered.org/t/node-red-crashes-with-email-node-imap/1489/6